# Does React rerenders component when a prop is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have two components named `Parent` and `Child`. In `Parent` component I have a state named `lastName` which is passed to `Child` as a prop. Now after initial rendering of `Child` and `Parent`, if the `lastName` in `Parent` changed, will it cause `Child` component to rerender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you set the property via [*setState*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate). However, re-render in React isn't something you should be afraid of, it's very efficient due to [Virtual DOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html) usage.

Comment: Tnx for answer, I wasn't afraid because of inefficiency, but because it wouldn't re-render at all!

Comment: @Mehrdad it will, it's called React[ive] for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the child component you should use the following

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
   return this.props.lastname !== nextProps.lastname
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#shouldComponentUpdate

After that, in the child component you might need to update the state. To achieve that you can use componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  this.setState({
    lastname: nextProps.lastname
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Child component is only re-rendered when props `lastName` is being used in Child's render function and Parent use `setState` function to change `lastName`. Remember, React is one-way dataflow, if you want to re-render Child component right inside the Child, you must call an event which also trigger `setState` back to Parent component